# How can I use MySQL on a MAMP set up with CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, mamp

In my database.php file, I have

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'mylocaldomain:8889';
$db['default']['username'] = 'myusername';
$db['default']['password'] = 'mypassword';
$db['default']['database'] = 'mydb';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

I continually, get an error saying that it can't connect. Any help?

Comment: Are you able to connect using mysql_connect using the same credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'mylocaldomain:8889';
```

To:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
```

or:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

I think you're confusing your apache server's host/port with MySQL's host